# What's the difference between "où en est " and "où est"?

Tags: traduction, en

I recently came across a podcast episode titled "Où en est la 5G en France?".

How is that title's meaning different from that of "Où est la 5G en France?" ?

Answer (score 4):

"Où en est" asks about the progress of the 5G deployment in France. It can be translated as "Where are we at with...?" in English.

"Où est" asks about a location. I wouldn't word it that way but I would understand "Où est la 5G en France?" as "Where is 5G available in France?".

Answer (score 2):

Both questions ask about location, position, be it physical or figurative.
But « où en est » is about the relative position in a path (again, physical or not), while « où est » is more about the absolute position.
For example, « où est la voiture ? » asks about the location of a car.
« où en est la voiture [dans le circuit] ? » asks about the position inside a specific path, here a track.

In the case of 5G technology, « où est la 5G ? » could be used for asking where 5G antennae or reception areas are located. « où en est la 5G ? » will ask about the position depending on a context. Here it refers to the development and/or deployment of 5G in France.

Answer (score 1):

Le TLFi classe *en [être](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre)* comme un cas particulier de *être de* avec un pronom adverbial, servant à « marquer un moment ou une étape dans le déroulement ou l'évolution de quelque chose » et identifie des syntagmes comme *où en êtes-vous? voilà où nous en sommes; j'en suis au début; j'en suis là; nous (en) étions au dessert quand il est arrivé; il en est à son cinquième verre de vin* etc. On a donc une interrogation sur la « situation » au figuré du déroulement (*où en est...*), qui diffère d'une autre sur le lieu (*où est...*) ou qui pourrait servir à mettre l'accent sur l'absence d'une chose.